# How to run Windows program without sudo?

Tags: sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows subsystem for Linux. When I try to run any Windows program from bash, it seems to have no effect :

For example, the following does *NOT* launch notepad.exe (and silently fails)

```
$ /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
$ echo $?
1
```

However, I've found that I could be able to get rid of that if I "sudo" my command :

(the following *does* launch notepad)

```
$ sudo /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
```

However :

```
$ ls -l /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
-r-xr-xr-x 3 orabig orabig 181248 Mar 10 20:25 /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
```

Is there a way to avoid having to use `sudo` to launch any Windows executable ?

**Edit :** I do not have this issue anymore, and unfortunately, I have no clue what did fix this issue ! :(

**Edit 2:** ... and.. the day after, it's not working anymore. Thus, the behaviour is totally random and unexplained.

Comment: Some docs here>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help (I've read the doc before posting my question)

Comment: It feels like something is missing from your question. For instance, why are you trying to run `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe` instead of just `notepad.exe`? That is, it would make sense to me that WSL might require `sudo` for direct access to the primary Windows folder. You should be able to access other Windows programs from WSL in a similar fashion (just don't forget to specify the `.exe` extension).

Comment: In fact, "notepad.exe" was used as an example in my question, but I had the same issue with other programs (in other folders), and yes, I should have said that. But the fact is that I do not encounter the issue today, and I have no clue why (I did at least one reboot yesterday, so that's not the reason). So weird. I'm editing the question.

Comment: `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe` works fine on my windows box without sudo.. Also.. why is your case wrong for WINDOWS and system32?..

Comment: I don't know, but I'm not sure this has anything to do with the issue (as I said, I used "notepad.exe" as a sample, because it is also used in many docs, but I encounter the very same issue with any other exe I try)